# Sanctum is not working with subdomains in multi-tenant [Tenancy for Laravel]

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-sanctum, sanctum

I am using Tenancy for Laravel but failing to use sanctum on subdomains as I have to define  SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS wildcard or related to the Main domain.
Anyone can help me out.

Comment: You could try `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` instead for the domain, i don't know if it gonna work but worth a try

Comment: Already tried got " ErrorException" =  Undefined array key "HTTP_HOST"